# Warning: file_get_contents() failed to open stream

Tags: php

Currently, I am trying to get the results of a https website and I am getting this error while using simple_html_dom.php, can anybody give me an idea on how to fix this or what's potentially causing it?

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://crimson.gg/jackpot-history): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable in /tickets/simple_html_dom.php on line 75
```

Line line 75 of simple_html_dom.php is this.

```
function file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
{
// We DO force the tags to be terminated.
$dom = new simple_html_dom(null, $lowercase, $forceTagsClosed, $target_charset, $stripRN, $defaultBRText, $defaultSpanText);
// For sourceforge users: uncomment the next line and comment the retreive_url_contents line 2 lines down if it is not already done.
$contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
// Paperg - use our own mechanism for getting the contents as we want to control the timeout.
//$contents = retrieve_url_contents($url);
if (empty($contents) || strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
{
    return false;
}
// The second parameter can force the selectors to all be lowercase.
$dom->load($contents, $lowercase, $stripRN);
return $dom;
}
```

And the code I am currently using is.

```
$html = file_get_html('https://crimson.gg/jackpot-history');
foreach($html->find('#contentcolumn > a') as $element) 
{
    print '<br><br>';
    echo $url = 'https://crimson.gg/'.$element->href;
    $html2 = file_get_html($url);

    $title = $html2->find('#contentcolumn > a',0);
    print $title = $title->plaintext;       
}
```

[image]

Line 4.

```
foreach($html->find('#contentcolumn > a') as $element)
```

Comment: Maybe file not exist or you have no permission to read the file. Check file exist or permission

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain when I change it to `curl` it works, but it pulls the content from the preloader cloudflare page. I need to figure how to delay it so when the cloudflare page is expired then it scrapes  or to make the code above work.